# How to use Composite API in Jitterbit for inserting records in Salesforce?

Tags: api, composite, jitterbit

I need to insert records for Account and contacts in one go using Jitterbit, i have one flat file with all the infomation but i dont have external ids. So, i want to use Composite API SFDC in jitterbit for this operation.

So, anyone can help me with the composite API in jitterbit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Salesforce by any means, but it looks like the composite API is simply a REST API call.  That being the case you would simply need the target URL for the composite API, the credentials to use, and the request structure to send.

Once you have that, you simply create a transformation operation, with the following information.  The source will be the data that you are trying to send (reading from a file, it sounds), the target will be the Salesforce format file structure (with the data mapped between the source and target structures.  Then the target would be the Salesforce URL for their REST API.

Hope that helps out.